# Short cut for `Go to definition` of variables in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Extremely handy feature of many IDEs is being able to quickly locate any of your function/variable definitions by simply highlighting the function name, than right clicking and selecting `"Go to definition"`.

For example, Spyder IDE for Python has it (with a short-cut <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+ <kbd>G</kbd>):

```
def hello():
    print("by World")

# main program starts here
hello() # Highlight 'hello' in IDE and right mouse click to go to its definition above.
```

So, for RStudio, we want the same - You create a function:

```
hello <- function () print("hello")
# main program starts here
```

Then somewhere in your project, where you call it:

```
hello()
```

you should be able to quickly navigate to `hello()` definition, i.e., the lines above.

Does `RStudio` have it ? Does is it plan to have it ?
Any workaround ?

Comment: You can use the `F2` keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to above comments  -
RStudio does have wonderful way of getting to all function definitions (yours or from packages) through a short cut <kbd>F2</kbd>.

There's also a little icon showing magic wand (on top, left of "Run" icons) which leads you to several others useful code Editing/Tracing utilities, such as Extract Function / Variable etc.

Comment: When I try this on a dataframe, it doesn't highlight the definition in the code, it simply opens the data frame in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is `Go to file/function` BOX below MENU bar in R studio by which you could do it. Also it is short cut you could do it by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: Does not work. Here's my example: `hello <- function () print("Hello!")`. Then elsewhere in my file or project I call `hello()` and should be able to easily navigate to hello() definition - just like in Spyder or VisualStudio



hello

Comment: @jciloa, Thanks for letting me know, please do feel free to edit my post with details which you think are good for this post, thanks again for letting know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ? in console like: `?"function"` for searching the definition, if the function exists. Or use ?? like: `??"function"` for searching keywords in the whole documentary.

Comment: I mean for my own defined functions like `hello <- function () print("hello")`

Comment: @IVIM alright, didn't got that one. Maybe your solution is writing the function without brackets `hello` in terminal. This returns the code of the function.